# Задача по жадным алгоритмам

Tags: python, алгоритм

Ограничение времени: 1 с;
Ограничение памяти: 256Mб

N - количество предметов, M - количество купонов, items - список цен предметов, minimums - список минимальных цен предметов для использования купона, discounts - список скидок, которые дают купоны. Для применения купона i стоимость предмета x должна быть не менее minimums[i] и тогда цена предмета будет items[x] - discounts[i]. На 1 предмет максимум 1 купон. Найти минимальную стоимость всех предметов после применения купонов.

Первая строка - N, M (M ≤ 2 * 10^5)

Вторая строка - items (1 ≤ items[i] ≤ 10^9)

Третья строка - minimums (1 ≤ minimums[i] ≤ 10^9)

Четвёртая строка - discounts (1 ≤ discounts[i] ≤ minimums[i])

Примеры:

Вход:

```
2 3 
12 11 
12 11 11 
5 11 8
```

Выход:

```
4
```

Вход:

```
3 5 
4 13 2 
5 1 12 6 8 
3 1 8 3 6
```

Выход:

```
10
```

Одна из моих попыток решить это, но она не проходит по времени:

```
def solution(n, m, items, mins, dis): 
    items.sort() 
    coupons = sorted(zip(mins, dis)) 
 
    i = 0 
    j = 0 
    while i != n and items[i] < coupons[0][0]: 
        i += 1 
 
    while i < n and j < len(coupons): 
        while j + 1 < len(coupons) and coupons[j + 1][0] <= items[i]: 
            j += 1 
 
        if j > -1: 
            mx = max(coupons[:j + 1], key=lambda c: c[1]) 
            items[i] -= mx[1] 
            coupons.remove(mx) 
            j -= 1 
        i += 1 
 
 
    return sum(items)
```

Comment: Может, кто уже спрашивал об этой задаче?

Comment: Вы уже посмотрели соседнюю тему в "алгоритмах"?

Comment: @MBo, нашёл, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение не проходит по времени так как каждая итерация цикла требует времени *O(M)* для поиска максимума и его удаления. Общая сложность - *O(NM)*.

Если подходящие купоны хранить в [куче](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html), сложность итерации может быть уменьшена до *O(logM)*.

Куча в Питоне минимальная, нам нужна максимальная. Поэтому в кучу кладутся скидки с знаком минус. В остальном алгоритм следует вашим идеям:

```
import heapq


_, m = map(int, input().split())       # n, m
c = sorted(map(int, input().split()))  # c
ld = sorted(zip(
    map(int, input().split()),         # l
    map(int, input().split())          # d
))

s = 0
q = []
j = 0
for ci in c:
    s += ci
    while j < m and ld[j][0] <= ci:
        heapq.heappush(q, -ld[j][1])
        j += 1
    if q:
        s += heapq.heappop(q)

print(s)
```